# Django: Can the value of a DOM Element be passed to a TemplateTag?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Being new to the framework, I am faced with the problem of creating a view (index.html) which allows the user to select a certain value from an input element and show it.This value needs to be processed and the output of this process will be shown in the template.

Currently, I am getting a .txt file from an input element and storing its content inside a p element by means of a small js script. The content of this p element (text contained inside the file selected) is what I would need to pass to the template in order to process it with an external python library that I created. I am trying to use a TemplateTag with the following structure:

`def foo(value):
    ret = doOperations(value)
    return ret;`

However, I am not sure if TemplateTags can receive the value of a dom element since the examples in django's documentation only show TemplateTags used with variables passed from the view.

The ideal scenario would be somehow passing the value (a text element) directly to the template: `{{ valueOfDomElement|foo }}` where valueOfDomElement would be the content of my p element (text contained inside the file selected)

I would like to know if my approach to this problem is viable or how I should proceed in order to communicate correctly between templatetag (if needed) and view.

Comment: You can do it, but it's limited. `{{ "text_element"|function:"other_text" }}`

Comment: I think you might have failed to understand the distinction between Django templates and JavaScript. Where is this "DOM element" coming from and how would you get it in order to pass it to the template tag?

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you included a more complete example of the code setting up the TemplateTag (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry for the poor explanation. I have an input file element in my template. From this input (onChange), I call a small js script that gets the content of a .txt file and stores it inside a <p> element. The problem comes when I need to process this data. The content of the file (stored in this p element) needs to be processed by a python program (initially external to the Django project). I figured this program could be imported and executed inside a templateTag since the result is also a string that must be shown.

Comment: Well, like I say, you seem to be misunderstanding the relationship between JS and Django. There is no way that a template tag, which is executed on the backend, could be called by a JS script, which is executed on the front end long after the template has been rendered. But why do you need to "store" the file data in an HTML element? Why don't you upload it directly to Django, either via a form or via Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT: Made changes based on your new comments to fit your idea better***

I think I understand what you're trying to do--I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that what you're wanting to do is impossible for Django's template language. Once Django serves the webpage to the enduser--any changes they make to the webpage, selecting dropdowns, etc., isn't accessible to the template logic anymore. The templates serve to deliver a final set of content from the server--once.

So if you want to access template tags--you can only access them as the server is building the page to send to the client--once the client/enduser has the .html content from the view/template--the template and view are no longer accessible for further manipulating the page.

If you need to actively communicate with the server based on user-interaction with dropdown selects / form changes etc., you can either A: submit the form with the user changes to the server View and refresh the page/template with those changes as template variables to feed back into the template with your template tags, or B: you can use AJAX to communicate with a simple Django view API that returns JSON for client page to process and makes changes.

I don't have time to give a B solution, but here is an A solution(which may be simple enough for your needs--as other people have stated--there isn't a lot to go on based on your description

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('fooView/', views.fooView, name='fooView'),
]
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def fooView(self, request, **kwargs)
    if request.GET:#If we are getting a form submission
        #Let's add any of the form data provided
        p_data = request.GET['your_paragraph_element']

        #Do something here with 'p_data' -- the data from your p element to process it in python

        #Now pass your processed p_data BACK to the template as a template variable
        kwargs['processed_p_data'] = p_data
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', kwargs)
```

## mytemplate.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="/fooView/" method="get">
<input name="your_paragraph_element" hidden></input>
<input type="file"></input>
{# If there IS 'processed_p_data' #}
{% if processed_p_data%}
<p id="foobar">{{processed_p_data}}</p>
{% else %}
<p id="foobar"></p>
{% endif %}

<input type="submit" value="Send Server My Change">
</form>
</body>

<script>
    //All of your jscript code that grabs the data from the file
    //--puts it into the <p> element
    //--also puts it into the hidden <input> element so that it can be sent to the server as form GET data
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly the answer I was looking for. Already working.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help!